# Set the selected attribute in a dropdown list if the condition is met in Angular2

Tags: forms, drop-down-menu, angular, ng-style

I have 2 objects in my project: a `company` and an `user`. I have a form where the user can update his profile. One of the things he can update is the country. Now to show the countries I use a dropdown list.

I want to set the `selected` attribute in the option where the `name` of the `country` is equal to the actual `country` of the `user`. (`country.name==user.country`)

This is what I have tried but It doesn't seem to work.

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="#c of countries" [ngStyle]="setStyles()" [ngValue]="c">{{c.name}}</option>          
</select>

setStyles(){
    let styles;
    if (this.companies[i].name == this.user.country ) {
        styles = {
            'selected'
        } 
    return styles;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="#c of countries"
       [attr.selected]="c.name == user.country ? true : null" 
       [ngValue]="c">
    {{c.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

I think that it's an attribute you need and not a style.

Comment: Thanks it works, but not on every user, but I think I need to tweak some of my code.